# How to update a tag with a bug fix

Tags: git, github, tags, git-tag

I need to be able to change my local repository to a particular tag, make a change, push the change and then git pull the tag+change on the production server. Here's where I'm stuck.

**Switch local repo to a particular tag**

```
git checkout v5.86
```

**Code changed on local repo**

**Push the tag to the production server?**

I tried git push but that said "Everything up-to-date" which is wrong? My change wasn't pushed to Github.

**How to pull the update to another server?**

Can I push the change to the tag?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any parameters, `git push` will push every "matching" branch that exists on both your server and the remote server, or everything under `git config remote.origin.push` if you've set it up that way.

Try `git push tag v5.86`, or `git push --tags`.

Read more about:

- [git config properties for remotes](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)
- [git push and its default parameters and behaviors](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html#_examples)